# When activity is recreated, detached fragment gets attached?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I have a Xamarin Android ActionBar-based app.  I am not using anybody's compat library (Sherlock, etc.)  I have a fragment for each tab.  I have noticed the following behavior:

Suppose the user starts on Tab A, with corresponding fragment A.  The user the switches to tab B, with corresponding fragment B.  My code tells the app to detach fragment A, and attach fragment B.  So far, so good.  Now the weird part.

Suppose the user rotates the device.  The fragments have all set

```
this.RetainInstance = true;
```

And I keep static references to them.  So they stick around, which is what I want.  But the weird thing is that when the activity is re-created after rotation, both fragments A and B get attached by Android, during my

```
base.OnCreate()
```

call from MyActivity.OnCreate().  This results in the app doing work which I assume is not needed.  So my question is, how can I prevent that from happening?

Comment: Fyi: this.setRetainInstance(true); (This is what is available in a v4.app.Fragment)

Answer (score 0):

You should read android guidelines. You must save the fragment state and the activity state and i suppose do not use static links and retainInstanceState. Google how to use Bundle and saveInstanceState, onCreate onRestoreInstancestate methods. Also after a recreation you can find you fragment by placed tag and reuse it without replace.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html